# Checking directory in PHP

Tags: php, directory, glob

```
$files = glob("C:/xampp/htdocs/karumia/karumia.txt");

    if ($files) {
    $stat =", Enjoy Shopping!";
    }
    if (!$files) {
    echo "
    alert(\"Please download and install the game first before accessing this page.\")
    document.location.href='../index.php'";
    }
```

this is a working code for checking a certain file. it works in a localhost but when I uploaded it for our website, I only get the result of "please download blah blah" even though the file exists. what should I do?

Comment: Use `file_exists()` function with `if` and `else`.

Comment: After uploading this to your remote site, Have you changed the path in the `glob` yet ?

Comment: i used the file_exists() function with if and else and I still got the same output :\
i changed the $files to $files = '//xampp/htdocs/karumia/karumia.txt';

Answer (score 1):

I sincerely hope you understand that this line checks whether the file exists ***on the server.*** You cannot check whether a file exists on the client's computer through the browser. Your server has no access to the client's file system, which is a good thing. There's no point in doing this check at all, you need to fundamentally fix your understanding of client/server communication and rethink what you're trying to do here.

<sub>(I'm assuming you *are* trying to check this file's existence on the client's computer, the question doesn't make sense interpreted any other way to me.)</sub>

Comment: hmm is there any way to check if a certain app/software is installed on the pc or not?

Comment: No, not from PHP. There may be under certain circumstances via Javascript if your application adds some browser extensions. But generally: no. Search for similar questions about exactly this topic, you're not the first to try.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [file_exists](http://www.php.net/file_exists):

```
<?php
$file = "karumia.txt"; // ASSUMING THAT YOUR SCRIPT RUNS IN "karumia" FOLDER
if(file_exists($file)){
   $stat =", Enjoy Shopping!";
}else{
   echo "alert(\"Please download and install the game first before accessing this page.\")
    document.location.href='../index.php'";
}

?>
```

Comment: The filepath `C:/xampp/htdocs/` is also a problem if he transfer the script to his webspace/server I doubt this directory remains the same.